# Best practice to design a graphql schema with numerous object types?

Tags: graphql

Every example of a grapqhl schema I found consisted of just a couple of ObjectTypes which all made sense in the global context of the schema like "Person", "Dog", "Animal".

In real life scenarios there are way more types. More importantly there might be types that make sense only within a group of other types but are called similarly e.g *StatisticsType*. *StatisticsType* held by a field inside a *GroupType* would be different than this held inside *PresentationType*. We could call them *GroupStatisticsType* and *PresentationStatisticsType*. However, following this approach I end up with types with very very long names.

As far as I know all types must be named uniquely within the schema and end up thrown in so to say one scope. Is there some design pattern, best practice or am I missing something that help to design a decent schema?

If you have any example of a schema with numerous types (20+ is something) might be helpful.

Comment: can you please put some nested types code

Comment: You might be interested in [GraphQL Interfaces](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces)

Comment: @marktani the interface concept is something completely different. I have just found this https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/163 where my problem is mentioned however no answer.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in long, descriptive type names? Beside being long?

Comment: At least the fact that your documentation is very hard to read [as for instance mentioned here.](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/163#issuecomment-285279416)